# Aws IAM group: Setup readonly access on log group on Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

Does someone know how to setup read-only access to specific log groups?

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "logs" {
  name        = "AWSLogs${title(var.product)}"
  description = "Logging policy for ${title(var.product)}"
  policy      = <<EOF
  {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "logs:Get*",
                    "logs:List*",
                    "logs:Filter*"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:logs:::log-group:${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.one.arn}:log-stream:*",
                    "arn:aws:logs:::log-group:${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.two.arn}:log-stream:*",
                    "arn:aws:logs:::log-group:${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.three.arn}:log-stream:*"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
   }
EOF
}


resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "logs" {
  group      = "${aws_iam_group.logs.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.logs.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "logs" {
  name = "${title(var.product)}Logs"
}
```

I'm currently struggeling to setup to only have access on specified log groups, but I can only get access to them when I set my resource to "*". This is not possible when I setup this dedicated to predefined log groups. Does someone have a good practice or solution? When I try this solution above I only get

> Not authorized to perform: logs:FilterLogEvents
>   , when I try to access it via an user which is part of the IAM group "logs".

Comment: Are you saying the policy in your code works or doesn't work? Can you show the working version and then the non working version and the error you get when you try to do something?

Comment: This is non working indeed! But when I update the whole policy with "*" on the resource people will be able to see all the logs which I don't want.

Comment: I already tried to add "arn:aws:logs:::log-group:product-group*:log-stream:*" but also same problem: Not authorized to perform: logs:FilterLogEvents.

Answer (score 1):

`aws_cloudwatch_log_group.one.arn` already is the full ARN of the `one` log group, i.e.,

> arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789012:log-group:one

So refer only to that in the `Resources` list:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "logs" {
  name        = "AWSLogs${title(var.product)}"
  description = "Logging policy for ${title(var.product)}"
  policy      = <<EOF
  {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "logs:Get*",
                    "logs:List*",
                    "logs:Filter*"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.one.arn}:log-stream:*",
                    "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.two.arn}:log-stream:*",
                    "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.three.arn}:log-stream:*"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
   }
EOF
}
```

Comment: Is not fixing my problem apparently! Getting the same error which is very frustrating. I think its a bug inside the AWS environment

Answer (score 0):

I was able to kind of solve this by adding a Condition filtering by tags to the Statement and making sure that the log groups and streams are tagged correspondingly:

```
"Condition": {
   "StringEquals": {
     "aws:ResourceTag/sometagname": "sometagvalue"
   }
}
```